# DataGrid row/column filtering

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing a Windows mobile application.  How can I show only two columns of the twelve in my datatable in the grid?.

Also, is it possible to delete rows in the Windows Mobile datagrid?

Please provide sample code.

---

Hi StartClass0830,

Thanks for your reply, i don't want remove the columns in my grid, Let's say  In the windows mobile application   the dtNewOrder table contains 11 columns i need to display the certain fields  from dtNewOrder to the datagrid.

And another question is the datagrid contains 10 rows how i am deleting the certain rows in the grid.

Please give me sample code; I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of days.

Here is what I have:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

 Dim dtCustomerName As DataTable
 Dim dtNewOrder As DataTable
 Dim _objDataAccess As New DataAccess

Private Sub NewOrder_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        dtNewOrder = CreateNewOrderDataTable()
 End Sub

 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles btnAdd.Click
     AddNewOrderMember(dtNewOrder)
End Sub

 Private Sub AddNewOrderMember(ByVal dtNewOrder As DataTable)
        Try
            Dim NewOrderMemberRow As DataRow = dtNewOrder.NewRow()
            NewOrderMemberRow("OrderID") = System.Guid.NewGuid()
            NewOrderMemberRow("SalesPersonID") = "123"
            NewOrderMemberRow("CustomerGroupID") = ddlCutomerGroup.SelectedValue.ToString()
            NewOrderMemberRow("CustomerID") = ddlCustomerName.SelectedValue.ToString()
            NewOrderMemberRow("CustomerItemCode") = "123"
            NewOrderMemberRow("Category") = "Dummy Category"
            'NewOrderMemberRow("Description") = "Dummy Des"
            NewOrderMemberRow("OrderUnit") = "Each"
            NewOrderMemberRow("OrderQuantity") = txtOrderQuantity.Text
            NewOrderMemberRow("UnitPrice") = "123"
            NewOrderMemberRow("TotalAmount") = "30000"
            dtNewOrder.Rows.Add(NewOrderMemberRow)
            dtNewOrder.AcceptChanges()

            If dtNewOrder.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                dgNewOrder.DataSource = dtNewOrder
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mobile Retail Merchandising", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        End Try
    End Sub


Private Function CreateNewOrderDataTable() As DataTable

        dtNewOrder = New DataTable("NewOrder")
        Try
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("OrderID", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SalesPersonID", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CustomerGroupID", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CustomerID", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CustomerItemCode", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Category", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Description", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("OrderUnit", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("OrderQuantity", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("UnitPrice", Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dtNewOrder.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TotalAmount", Type.GetType("System.String")))

            Dim PrimaryKeyColumns() As DataColumn = New DataColumn(1) {}
            PrimaryKeyColumns(0) = dtNewOrder.Columns("OrderID")
            dtNewOrder.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns
            Return dtNewOrder
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mobile Retail Merchandising", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            Return dtNewOrder
        End Try
    End Function
```

Thanks
 brite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat problematic.  You mentioned 2 columns in your grid and 12 columns in your datatable and you want to delete ROWS!

I take it you mean COLUMNS instead of ROWS.  When you do data-binding to your grid, you can specify which columns in the 12 you want.  There is no need to delete columns.

In the event, you REALLY mean ROWS, you can modify your SQL or LINQ queries to have those unwanted ROWS removed.

Comment: @StartClass0830: FYI, the OP has posted a clarification. Which hopefully I haven't mangled when I moved it to the question.